# Call to undefined method GetStream\\Stream\\Feed::followFeed()

Tags: php, laravel

I am using getstream in laravel project. When calling followUser method of StreamLaravelManager class, it does not find followFeed method inside the package. What may be the problem here?

```
\FeedManager::followUser($follower->follow_id, $follower->user_id);
```

Above line of code is triggering the method.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Updated with code i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot know what might be wrong here, but changing the get stream version solved this issue. Changed "get-stream/stream-laravel": "^2.2" to "get-stream/stream-laravel": "~2.2.6" in my composer and it solved . the issue.